# Protobuf-net "No parameterless constructor found for Binary"

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, protobuf-net

i have a class which is bellow

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
    public class BelgeDosyasi : TablesBase
    {
        public BelgeDosyasi()
        {


        }
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public Binary HizmetBelgeDosya { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string HizmetBelgeUzantisi { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public int HizmetBelgeBoyutu { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public string HizmetBelgeAdi { get; set; }
    }
```

This class help to download a binary file from database, without protobuf it works very fine but after starting to use protobuf on object deserialization i received this error "No parameterless constructor found for Binary" and am not able to solve the problem.
my protobuf-net version is Version=2.0.0.668. any help is appreciated.

```
    at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ThrowCannotCreateInstance(Type type) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 1397
   at proto_8(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 57
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 775
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 579
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 566
   at proto_6(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 57
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 775
   at ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.XmlProtoSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ServiceModel\XmlProtoSerializer.cs:line 193
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)



at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ThrowCannotCreateInstance(Type type) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 1397
   at proto_8(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 57
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 775
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 579
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 566
   at proto_6(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\CompiledSerializer.cs:line 57
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 775
   at ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.XmlProtoSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ServiceModel\XmlProtoSerializer.cs:line 193
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Comment: What is `Binary` in this example? Is this your own type? or some type from EF / some-random-framework / ???

Comment: Dear Marc, thank you very much for your response, yes i found out that the exception was from the Binary type it self which is av type inherits from Linq.Binary. Converting it to Byte[] solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Marc, thank you very much for your response, yes i found out that the exception was from the Binary type it self which is av type inherits from Linq.Binary. Converting it to Byte[] solved the problem.